# What is the timing of ClearOutput method in OPOS-OLE for Retail POS?

Tags: visual-c++, opos

I am developing an interface of OPOS for CAT-Credit Authorization Terminal using VC++ 2010. My question is about ClearOutput method if anyone here have tried coding opos controls. When I call that function it returns code 106 which means OPOS_E_ILLEGAL.

here are the sequence of my code:

- OPOSCAT.Open()
- OPOSCAT.ClaimDevice()
- OPOSCAT.DeviceEnabled = True
- OPOSCAT.Asyncmode = true
- Perform SALES and it fires event, wait until it's finish, calls OutputCompleteEvent
- OPOSCAT.ClearOutput()
- OPOSCAT.DeviceEnabled = False
- OPOSCAT.Asyncmode = False
- OPOSCAT.ReleaseDevice()
- OPOSCAT.Close()

Click here for more reference:
[See Chapter 5](http://www.wincor-nixdorf.com/internet/cae/servlet/contentblob/70234/publicationFile/6404/...)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, that PDF is for 1.6, which is over 15 years out of date.  See http://monroecs.com/unifiedpos.htm for the current version of OPOS, which is 1.14.  If nothing else you should upgrade for PCI compliance reasons.

OPOS Common Controls are pretty generic, and wouldn't have a lot of reasons to return that error on the `clearOutput()` method.  The only thing I can think of would be if it's not in a legal state (claimed) to call it.  Perhaps the previous call created an error condition so bad the device changed the state from claimed to released?

If that's not it, it's probably a device specific error.  Contact the device vendor who provided the service object.  You could try downloading the debug version of OPOS and enabling logging, which would provide more evidence to support this claim.

Answer (score 0):

For details, please check the specification of the CAT service object you are using.

Probably because ClearOutput was called after OutputCompleteEvent, that is, after asynchronous processing of SALES has ended.

In general, the ClearOutput method is called to cancel the processing during asynchronous processing.
In your code, it is part of "wait until it's finish".

If you call the ClearOutput method while waiting for this completion, the ClearOutput method will succeed and the SALES operation (such as AuthorizeSales) will be canceled.

However, depending on the specification of the CAT service object you are using, the service object may not support the ClearOutput method.
In that case, an error occurs regardless of the time of the call.